# How to get index and column of max value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the index and value (non-zero) which have a max total.

```
A = np.matrix([[0,2,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [1,3,0,1],])
slst = ['S1','S2','S3','S4']
namelist= ['Alice','John','Joe']
df =  pd.DataFrame(A,columns = slst, index = namelist)
df.loc['total'] = df.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum()
print (df)
```

```
Output:
       S1  S2  S3  S4
Alice   0   2   1   0
John    0   0   0   0
Joe     1   3   0   1
total   1   5   1   1
```

And I want to get the result from this table below.
How to get it?

```
Output1:
Alice: 2,
Joe: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `df.loc['total']`, try:

```
total = df.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum()
df[total.idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
Alice    2
John     0
Joe      3
total    5
Name: S2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work also:

```
df1 = df.max(axis=1)
df1
```

---

```
       S1  S2  S3  S4
Alice   0   2   1   0
John    0   0   0   0
Joe     1   3   0   1
total   1   5   1   1

Alice    2
John     0
Joe      3
total    5
dtype: int64
```